# Wamp server on windows 10 does not start; gives error 0x0000007b' What needs change?

Tags: php, apache, wamp

On startup following error shown:
Error 0x0000007b.

Tried options :
(a) chkdsk c: /f/r
(b) Run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have an up-to-date Visual C++ distribution which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).

You might also want to check you have the correct WAMP version fo your computer (either 32-bit or 64-bit).